Risks of generating photosynthetic yeast
The paper "Engineering artificial photosynthetic life-forms through endosymbiosis" (Cournoyer, 2022) describes the creation of a new endosymbiosis between yeast and cyanobacteria, which was followed up with "Introducing carbon assimilation in yeasts using photosynthetic directed endosymbiosis " (Gao, 2024).  The organisms are capable of replicating for multiple generations, though the first paper found the symbionts are eventually lost.  The second paper suggests further work; to quote the abstract: "We anticipate that our studies will have significant implications for sustainable biotechnology, synthetic biology, and experimentally studying the evolutionary adaptation of an additional organelle in yeast."  I did not notice any mention of safety, disposal, or BSL levels in these papers.
Suppose that some of these organisms are released in a waterway.  I'm imagining that the cyanobacterium could lose genomic material, become more efficient to maintain, and be retained in the cells by selective pressures.  I wonder if the organisms that evolve from this process would be reasonably efficient but turn out to be less palatable or even toxic to primary consumers (perhaps due to the intended chemical product for which the organism is engineered).  I wonder if this could in turn snap the food web and leave the waterways in a state of disaster akin to eutrophication.  Question: is this concern warranted?  What is the level of risk from pursuing this line of research?

In summary, your concerns are not unwarranted.
This work will result in a formal risk assessment for GMOs and will be sanctioned by the GMO committee. They will assess the risk of GMO escape and associated containment facilities required. For example, any work on Ebola virus is automatically category 4 (cat4), where the investigators use oxygen tanks and full safety "jump-suits". They will shower when leaving the facilities and nothing that enters the containment lab is permitted to leave without high temperature sterilisation, except for the investigators of course.
Accidents happen, African killer-bees terrorise native bee populations in the Americas stemming from a laboratory escape in Brazil. Obviously there other possible escapees, which are both disputed and debated, that are far more dangerous (SARS-CoV-2).
I would personally categorise the risk for this GMO as Cat 2 (regular lab), but I've never sat on a GMO committee. What I would believe is that a GMO escapee would not compete again indigenous yeasts, therefore would not be a threat. If there was evidence to the contrary the work would be escalated to Cat 3: which are difficult to work on and hemmed in by regulations.
The African killer-bee disaster however serves as a warning that assumptions about adaptability and invasive species in a foreign ecoregion can be very badly flawed.

Africanised bees in the USA Scientific American 1993, link maintained by the USDA. The situation has got a lot worse since then.

This answer could be improved with references, links in support of the assertions.
